# How to get rid of sort-bar in Mail app?

Tags: macos, mail.app

Since I upgraded to Yosemite, the Mail app shows an irritating sort bar at the bottom of the message list. I like to view my email messages with the oldest message on the top. But now this sort bar is overlapping the newest message at the bottom.
Is there a way to move the sort bar to the top, or get rid of it all together?

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot? There are so many view options in Mail, & 2 basic view styles, that it's hard to figure out without something to look at. Blur any personal info, of course, then upload to any file sharing site & add the link to your post. Someone with the necessary rep can then inline it for you.

Comment: Thanks Tetsujin. I made a screenshot and you can find it here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/w74kmakao7vvjaz/mail%20sort%20bar.png?dl=0

Comment: The first thing I'd try would be Prefs > Viewing > 'Use classic layout' & see if you get on better with that. I switched off the new layout the first day it appeared ;) I just tried it in 'modern' view & I cannot get that sort bar to appear at the bottom at all; it's at the top for me.

Comment: Classic Layout does the trick indeed, THANKS. I would like to have the message pane on the right side though. Do you know if that's possible? I can't find a setting for that.

Comment: In "modern" view, try reversing the sorting order: get the newest message at the bottom. Then the sort bar will move down as well.

Comment: Not as far as I know, classic puts the pane underneath.. old-school-style

Comment: I'd tried flipping the sort order - I didn't move the bar for me. Not sure what else may be involved

Comment: I turned the preference back to "modern" and now the sort bar is on top, like it should. Quitting Mail and restarting it, brings te sort bar back beneath. Flipping to classic layout and back to modern does the trick. Silly, but a workaround I can live with. Thank you Tetsujin!!

Comment: Glad you got it :)